# Azure DNS Records Not Propagating

Tags: azure, dns

I am having issues with my Azure DNS records propagating. Azure automatically created these records in the DNS server after I tried to hook up my custom domain from my static web application. Now it is just spinning on "validating" and no external DNS checking tools are showing any info.

Is there anything I can do to force these records to propagate?

[image]

Comment: Hi @AdamGlasser, did the suggested solution work for you? Do let me know if it solved your problem else share more details so I can troubleshoot or else do accept it for helping other community members.

Answer (score 1):

•   First, please check whether your **custom domain name is verified in Azure or not and its public DNS records are correctly retrieved and verified for custom DNS record verification**. As you are mapping your custom domain with your static website, would suggest you to please **ensure that a CNAME record is created in your DNS record set for the static website endpoint**.

•   And if the CNAME record is created, then you can **access your static website with the CNAME record alias**. If not, then **wait for 24-48 hours for this DNS mapping to be completed at your public DNS zone server**. Once done, then try to **‘nslookup’ the public FQDN of the static website endpoint or CNAME alias from an internet enabled Windows system** as follows. It will showup as **authoritative response and popup a public IP address** for that FQDN or if the public DNS server’s certification authority is not trusted, then it will show up as **‘non-authoritative’ and show up the IP address of the static website**.

```
 nslookup
 Azstaticwebsite.customdomain.com
```

Output: -

[image: NSLOOKUP]

•   Also, if the **custom domain is owned by you and publicly reachable, then try to ping it from the command prompt**, you will get a response with IP address as reachable or not. And do **ensure that the domain name ‘arglasser.com’ is owned by you and you have it verified as a custom domain in Azure** because `if it is not, then all your DNS records formed might not get validated and your website will not be publicly available`.

For more information regarding this, kindly refer to the below documentation link: -

**https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-custom-ssl?tabs=option-1-default-enable-https-with-a-cdn-managed-certificate**